# How to pass variables through classes in Tkinter Python?

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I really don't know how to pass variables through different classes. Searched som info here and found that there methods like **Controller an Global Variables** , I "tried them" but didn't work.
I post here the code (easy code made for the example): 
Thanks in advance

```
class One:
    def __init__(self,maste`enter code here`r): #añadimos aqui el controller
        labelFrame = LabelFrame(master,text="DATA")
        labelFrame.pack()
        Label(labelFrame,text="NAME").pack()
        self.name = StringVar()
        Entry(labelFrame,textvariable=self.name).pack()

        Label(labelFrame,text="AGE").pack()
        self.age = StringVar()
        Entry(labelFrame,textvariable=self.age).pack()

        Button(labelFrame,text="GO",command=self.go).pack()


    def go(self):
        toplevel = Toplevel(root)
        tab = Two(toplevel)


class Two:
    def __init__(self,master): #añadimos aqui el controller
        labelFrame = LabelFrame(master,text="OPERATION")
        labelFrame.pack()
        self.hoy = datetime.datetime.today()
        Button(labelFrame,text="Go Futher mm!",command=self.operate).pack()

    def operate(self):
        if self.nombre.get()!=None and self.edad.get()!= None:
            print(f"User {self.name.get()} is: {self.age.get()} years old ")
root = Tk()
x = One(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can access `self.name` in `class Two` using `x.name`. It's also possible to extend `Two(toplevel, self)` and `def __init__(self, master, one):` which allows to do `one.name`.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what means x.name. For the second way if you have to access a couple of variables, let's say 10, doing that way is not bit bulky? So controller method is not profitable to do in this kind of functions? (thanks a lot anyway :) ). Thanks in advance

Comment: ***"don't understand what means `x.name`."***: In your example `x` is a reference to `class One`. To access the class attribute `self.name` you can use `<reference to class One>.<class attribute>` which is `x.name` Read [Python - Object Oriented](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm)

Comment: ***"second way ... access a couple of variables,"***: You can access **ALL** class attributes, e.g. `one.name` and `one.age` with the same reference `one`. Read [Python - Object Oriented](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm)

Comment: Yes! thank you for your support :). I have done it